# Resize iframe on button click inside the iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am using the following code to resize an iframe based on its content:

**Inside the iframe**

```
function resizeiframe() {
  window.parent.postMessage(
    document.getElementById("widget-container").offsetHeight
    ,"*"
  );
};


window.onload = function() {
  resizeiframe();
};
```

**In the parent**

```
<iframe src="https://myurl.com"
        frameborder="0"
        scrolling="no"
        width="100%"
        id="my-iframe"
        name="my-iframe"
        allowtransparency="true"
        target="_blank">
  Your browser is not supported.
</iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var myEventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
    var myEventListener = window[myEventMethod];
    var myEventMessage = myEventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";
    myEventListener(myEventMessage, function (e) {
        if (e.data === parseInt(e.data))
            document.getElementById('my-iframe').height = e.data + "px";
            alert(e.data);
    }, false);
</script>
```

It works pretty well (for testing I alert e.data in the parent). However, if I want the iframe to resize on a click it does not work.

**Button inside the iframe**

```
$(document).on("click", ".show-recipe-btn", function(){
  window.parent.postMessage(
    2000
    ,"*"
  );
});
```

When I click on the button from the example code the parent alerts 2000, which is correct, but the iframe height does not change.

**What do I have to change to make the iframe resize on button click?**

> **UPDATE** I just realized that once the button is clicked it fires 2000 but right after that window.onload fires again.
>
> New question: I need window.onload function to send the
>   widget-container height, and on the button click I need to send the height of another id. How can I rewrite my code to make that work?

Comment: What happens when you type `document.getElementById('my-iframe').height` in your console?

Comment: if I console.log this then it puts first 2000 and then 595 (which is the height on initial load. ok seems like the button click fires 2000 and right after that window.onload fires again and resets to height of #widget-container. any idea how to change that?